Ubuntu 22.04 freezes/crashes when suspended
HP zBook 15G6, 6-core with 48GB RAM.
I had it running Ubuntu 16.04 - 20.04 since 2019. It occasionally freezes and necessitated, a cold restart. But after upgrading to 22.04 a week ago, it freezes every few hours randomly, After I upgraded the BIOS, it starts to crash login GUI session more frequently and every time I suspend it.
Before this, I saw crash log files being uploaded to ubuntu support site. But when it crashes at suspension, no such upload has been recorded in the /var/crash directory. So I also get no clue why it crashes.
I saw similar reports about crash at suspension since 2021. Would someone who has got the issue resolved share some insight?
thanks so much!

Same problem here. Have you found any solution?

I installed many ubuntu on many different machines, and have the same situation as you, you can try the following:

check log in /var/log/syslog, /var/log/kern.log see if you find anything
Check to see if the hard drive is working properly
Check the graphics driver
Check if it is affected by other utilities
Update software and kernel.
...

Hope to help you

This is a comment not an answer. An answer solves the issue and is not just a list of troubleshooting steps.

After a few recent updates, the problem went away! I guess it was the developers who worked diligently in the background fixed the issue reported by the uploaded crash log. ... my salute to the contributors ...

I have HP Probook 4740s and this is what helped me. Here is the link to the original answer and a quote from it:

I was having this exact same problem on my HP Pavilion 14 on Ubuntu 22.04. It worked fine a few days ago but I encountered this problem after an update. Lots of stack answers pointed to some problems with Nvidia drivers, but I don't have Nvidia graphics. I have an integrated AMD Radeon along with AMD Ryzen 7.
What worked for me:
Installing amdgpu-install and installing the AMD graphic cards components[2] after checking the secure boot support[3]:
amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics
[2]https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-overview.html 
[3]https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-installing.html#ubuntu-and-debian-based-systems

UPD:
But there was the downside in my case. OS(Ubuntu 22.04) stopped being smooth, animations stopped working and laptop cooler started to be more noisy.
